# I am getting Cannot Get/ error in Angular

Tags: angular

I am getting this on browser Cannot Get/.

Its showing me this error,

```
sidebar.component.html:2:58 - error TS2322:
Type 'Category' is not assignable to type 'any[] & Iterable<any>'.
Type 'Category' is not assignable to type 'any[]'.
```

//My codes are here

> sidebar.components.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ProductService } from 'src/app/products/product.service';
import { Category } from '../category';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sidebar',
  templateUrl: './sidebar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sidebar.component.css']
})
export class SidebarComponent implements OnInit {

  categoryList !: Category; // here it was giving error so i putt ! 
  constructor(private ProductService : ProductService) { }
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.ProductService.getCategory().subscribe(data => {
      this.categoryList = data;
    })
  }
}
```

caregory.ts

```
export interface Category {

    id:string;
    productName:string;
}
```

sidebar.component.html

```
<div class="list-group">
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let catg of categoryList"> 
        {{catg.categoryName}}
    </a>
</div>
```

> *all the paths , folders & projects location are all correct.*

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The type of your property should be `Category[]` since you're expecting an array. You're also iterating over an undefined property because of the asynchronous nature of your HTTP call. To fix that, you should initialize that property as an empty list.

```js
categoryList: Category[] = [];
```

You might want to avoid subscribing manually in the controller and instead subscribe in the template by using the async pipe for performance reasons (also by following the best practices).

To do that, you can use this snippet in the controller:

```js
categoryList$: Observable<Category[]>;

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.categoryList$ = this.ProductService.getCategory().pipe(
        shareReplay() // in case you want to share the data
     )
  }
```

And in the template:

```html
<div class="list-group">
   <ng-container *ngIf="categoryList$ | async as categoryList">
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let catg of categoryList"> 
        {{catg.categoryName}}
      </a>
   </ng-container>
</div>
```